# Reusing the Java (de)serialization in implementing Externalizable

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I would like to implement `java.io.Externelizable` that essentially says do whatever `java.io.Serializable` would do with some modifications. What hooks, if any, are there into the Java serialization mechanism? Alternatively are there any external libraries that accurately emulate the Java serialization mechanism in an open/extensible way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to implement `java.io.Externalizable` for small customizations to serialization. Just implement `java.io.Serializable` as before and implement the following two methods in the class:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) {
    oos.defaultWriteObject();
    // custom serialization
    oos.writeInt(notSerializableObj.getId());
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) {
    ois.defaultReadObject();
    // custom de-serialization
    notSerializableObj = new NotSerializableObj(ois.readInt());
}
```

`java.io.Externalizable` is mostly used when you want to completely change the way your object is serialized (the underlying algorithm itself) for performance or security reasons.